# Transmission Rebuild or Replacement

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, manual-transmission, replace, rebuild

I have been reading and hearing about transmission rebuilding or replacement. Today a person was asking if they should sell their car or keep repairing it (it had a transmission problem). Notice that most of the times that I hear about transmission rebuilding or replacement was from someone in USA and mechanics asking 2k-3k $.

Nevertheless, one of the answers said that a transmission should be able to handle 30k miles (~50k km) with no problems.

**Thus my question would be if this is a normal thing to change atleast once the transmission of a car. Does it make a difference if the car is manual or automatic?**

My parents's cars are manual and have not even once changed transmission for more than 180k km or even 300k km.

Comment: R&R or R&I plus a rebuild on most transverse engine transmissions is labor intensive. You can easily hit 20 hrs doing the job and when you figure anywhere from $90-120 USD labor rate it’s not out of the norm to be quoted in that range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a transmission should last for the lifetime of the car, assuming regular maintenance (regular oil/filter change according the specification).

On manual transmissions the clutch (and dual mass flywheel, if equipped) is a wear item. 
Those repairs are one of the "big jobs", where the owner needs to decide if the effort is worth it.

The average cost a of a clutch job is very difficult to tell, as the work-hours and part prices vary highly. Assume 1000-1500$ for a clutch job, some more in case of an equipped dual mass flywheel.

The wear depends highly on type of usage (highway use vs. stop and go), driving style and type of car, but a clutch life of 150 kkm to 200 kkm should be in the average. It can be drastically reduced by bad driving habits.

Comment: It also depends very much on the usage of the vehicle. Three hours driving on a freeway or motorway with light traffic clocks up plenty of miles, but you might never touch the clutch pedal at all in that time. Three hours in stop-start city traffic - negligible mileage, but hundreds of clutch pedal depressions.

Comment: @alephzero My intention was that the highway-use was included in the "driving style" condition

Comment: @Myself I was thinking the "driving style" was about those drivers who slip the clutch for 5 minutes while pulling away....

Comment: A dual mass flywheel and clutch replacement is £800-1000 in the UK...

Comment: @SolarMike apparently "my garage of least mistrust" tried to sell me off.

Comment: @Myself I think if you use the exchange rate the prices are the same... but it does depend on the car - some are more challenging so the labour goes up...

Comment: It depends a lot on the design. Clutch replacement on the old farm truck is a few bolts, lower the transmission six inches, and take off an access panel.  A couple of hours work at most.  On a compact trans-axle design it's usually more like pull the whole engine and hope you have all the specialty tools to put it back together again. Lots of newer transmissions are considered to be unrepairable past a certain point as assembling them can only practically be done on the machines that build them in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no, Auto boxes may need more frequent oil changes, but, properly looked after they can do 100K or 200K just as easily as a manual box.

For a manual box the issue tends to be the clutch - as some drivers are "more sympathetic" to the clutch and treat it better, but some need a new clutch every 30K (like those customers : clutch change can be easy money...)

Comment: and auto boxes can easily be trashed if oil change is done incorrectly, not that big issue with manual box